# How to view custom web fonts with "eot ttf woff " extensions?

Tags: fonts

I would like to view custom fonts that I have in the following file extensions: .eot .ttf and .woff

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [this web font generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) with excelent results.

You need to upload the fonts you want to use in your page, it is easy and free. Hope this helps!

Comment: It only allows TTF but not other formats.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but for anyone looking for a solution: https://transfonter.org/ is what worked perfectly for my needs (I wanted to preview some woff).